# add individual resultsets to ListView

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am struggling with a UI element. 
I am using Android and SQL server stored procedures. 
I am looking for a way to add individual resultsets to a ListView.

most of my research seems to find when the resultset already contains more than one row, where mine will only return one row at a time/ per event trigger

`onClick` will trigger a select statement which will return one row of results.
This will happen on each click and the list should grow on each click (adding new item), but for me the item in the list replaces the first item on click.

```
    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
    connect = con;
    lstBales= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstBales);


    PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("EXEC SelectbyId '" + ItemID.toString() + "'");
    final ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    rs = statement.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        list.add(rs.getString("col1")+","+ rs.getString("col2")+","+ rs.getString("col3")+","+ rs.getString("col4"));
       }
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ReadActivityTwo.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    lstBales.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Is this code for your `onclick` method??

Comment: This code is in a method that gets called depending on a value of a particular variable, but that value gets set in a onclick method in a different class. ( I sort of inherited that structure from a different developer)

Comment: can I have your whole code? So I can edit it?

Comment: I would give it all, but after mapping out what was done its seems to be a bit complex. It has classes that extend other classes looks like it is nested 4 classes deep and the fourth class is extending the activity, which is causing some limitation on when you have access to user interface controls. I don't want to task you with editing that. (guess that's my job ), but thanks for the offer. I appreciate your willingness to help me.

Comment: If rs only returns 1 value then only 1 value will be added to **list** the new **adapter** instance will then only show **1 item**. I'd suggest moving **list** to have greater scope and instantiating the adapter only once (say in onCreate, declared as a class variable, as with list). Do the `list.add` (as you do now) then do `adapter.notiftDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

you should use `Cursor` for fetching rows from table.

```
public ArrayList<HomeClass> getdata() {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    cursor = DBConstant.sqliteDatabase.query(your query);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                list = new ArrayList<>();
                String postid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBConstant.TBL_MULTIPLE_IMAGE.POST_ID));
                String multipleImagepath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBConstant.TBL_MULTIPLE_IMAGE.SET_MULTI_IMAGE));

              // here your modal class which stores one row data .
                homeclass = new HomeClass(); 
                homeclass.setPost_id(postid);
                homeclass.setmultipleImagepath (multipleImagepath );

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());


            list.add(homeclass);

        }
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }

   return list;
}
```

Use this method above `Adapter` set . after calling this method add code

```
final ArrayList<HomeClass> list = new ArrayList();
list=getdata();

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ReadActivityTwo.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
lstBales.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I don't know Cursor, can you tell me why it is a better approach than PrepareStatement? 

Also I am using SQL Server and not SQLite, dont know if that makes a difference to the use of Cursor. 

thanks